# obtain values from MySQL table using PHP and display results in jQuery function as "option"

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I am facing an issue as regards the following:

1) I have retrieved "select->options" values using PHP MySQL as below:

```
$fetch_sub_categories1 =    '{ label: "", value: "" },';
$fetch_sub_categories2 =    '{ label: "", value: "" },';
$fetch_sub_categories3 =    '{ label: "", value: "" },';
$fetch_sub_categories4 =    '{ label: "", value: "" },';


$num_of_returned_rows = mysqli_num_rows($get_sub_cats_query);        
if ($num_of_returned_rows>0)
{
for ($i=0;$i<$num_of_returned_rows;$i++)
{
     $row=mysqli_fetch_array($get_sub_cats_query);

     if ($row['category'] == 'Αρχικά Πιάτα'){
        if($i==$num_of_returned_rows) $fetch_sub_categories1 .= '{ label: ""'.$row['sub_category'].'"", value: ""'.$row['sub_category'].'"" }';
        else                          $fetch_sub_categories1 .= '{ label: ""'.$row['sub_category'].'"", value: ""'.$row['sub_category'].'"" },';
     }
     if ($row['category'] == 'Κυρίως Πιάτα') {
        if($i==$num_of_returned_rows) $fetch_sub_categories2 .= '{ label: ""'.$row['sub_category'].'"", value: ""'.$row['sub_category'].'"" }';
        else                          $fetch_sub_categories2 .= '{ label: ""'.$row['sub_category'].'"", value: ""'.$row['sub_category'].'"" },';
     }
     if ($row['category'] == 'Επιδόρπια')   {
        if($i==$num_of_returned_rows) $fetch_sub_categories3 .= '{ label: ""'.$row['sub_category'].'"", value: ""'.$row['sub_category'].'"" }';
        else                          $fetch_sub_categories3 .= '{ label: ""'.$row['sub_category'].'"", value: ""'.$row['sub_category'].'"" },';
     }
     if ($row['category'] == 'Ποτά')         {
        if($i==$num_of_returned_rows) $fetch_sub_categories4 .= '{ label: ""'.$row['sub_category'].'"", value: ""'.$row['sub_category'].'"" }';
        else                          $fetch_sub_categories4 .= '{ label: ""'.$row['sub_category'].'"", value: ""'.$row['sub_category'].'"" },';
     }
}
```

}

2) I have a ready document listener jQuery function which I use to display the above results as below:

```
label: "Υποκατηγορία:",
                                name: "sub_category",
                                type:  "select",
                                options: [

                                        '<?php echo $fetch_sub_categories1; ?>'
                                ]
```

However the browser interprets the whole variable `$fetch_sub_categories1` as a string and does not display the options as defined within the variable.

The result as below:

[image]

Any advice will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the single quotes around the `<?php ?>` tag:

```
label: "Υποκατηγορία:",
name: "sub_category",
type: "select",
options: [
    <?php echo $fetch_sub_categories1; ?>
]
```

They are the reason why the content of `$fetch_sub_categories1` is interpreted as a string.

Comment: Thank you for the response. i tried that but if i do it without quotes the jquery fails.

Comment: That's because you have 2 double quotes (`""`) around each label and value (except the first, empty ones).

Comment: @A.A.PEACE Try with only 1 single quote around each label and value: `'{ label: "'.$row['sub_category'].'", value: "'.$row['sub_category'].'" }'`

Comment: Worked friend thank you. Your advice helped a lot.  i have changed  single quotes to double quotes of the  $fetch_sub_categories1 declaration within php and in the jquery as you said (without any quotes)